# Kotlin Sorting a list of objects based on their coordinate( lat and long) using Haversine formula

Tags: kotlin, generics

I want to sort a list based on their latitude and longitude...
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import java.io.File
import java.io.InputStream
import java.util.Comparator

data class Property(val Pcode: Int, val Locality: String, val State: String, val Comments: String, val Category: String, val Longitude: Double, val Latitude: Double)


class SortPlaces(currentLatitude: Double, currentLongitude: Double) : Comparator<Property> {
    var currentLat: Double
    var currentLng: Double
    override fun compare(property1: Property, property2: Property): Int {
        val lat1: Double = property1.Latitude
        val lon1: Double = property1.Longitude
        val lat2: Double = property2.Latitude
        val lon2: Double = property2.Longitude
        val distanceToPlace1 = distance(currentLat, currentLng, lat1, lon1)
        val distanceToPlace2 = distance(currentLat, currentLng, lat2, lon2)
        return (distanceToPlace1 - distanceToPlace2).toInt()
    }

    fun distance(fromLat: Double, fromLon: Double, toLat: Double, toLon: Double): Double {
        val radius = 6378137.0 // approximate Earth radius, *in meters*
        val deltaLat = toLat - fromLat
        val deltaLon = toLon - fromLon
        val angle = 2 * Math.asin(
            Math.sqrt(
                Math.pow(Math.sin(deltaLat / 2), 2.0) +
                        Math.cos(fromLat) * Math.cos(toLat) *
                        Math.pow(Math.sin(deltaLon / 2), 2.0)
            )
        )
        return radius * angle
    }

    init {
        currentLat = currentLatitude
        currentLng = currentLongitude
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val command = Scanner(System.`in`)
    val running = true

    while (running) {

        val inputStream: InputStream = File("./src/main/kotlin/suburbs.json").inputStream()
        val inputString = inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
        val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
        val packagesArray = gson.fromJson(inputString , Array<Property>::class.java).toList()

        println("Please enter a suburb name: ")
        val suburbName = command.nextLine()

        println("Please enter the postcode: ")
        val postcode = command.nextLine()

        val userProperty: Property? = packagesArray.find{ it.Locality.toLowerCase().equals(suburbName.toLowerCase()) && it.Pcode == postcode.toInt()}

        //sort the list, give the Comparator the current location
        Collections.sort(packagesArray, new SortPlaces(userProperty.Latitude, userProperty.Longitude));


    }
    command.close()
}
```

I got error: Too many arguments for public open fun <T : Comparable<T!>!> sort(list: (Mutable)List<T!>!): Unit defined in java.util.Collections
at my sort{} function
my userProperty has to be Property? because the find{} method return Property?
Then Collections.sort() can not sort Property? type because the SortPLaces only accept Comparator not Comparator<Property?>
What should I do?

Comment: `new SortPlaces`? `Collections.sort`? Did you confuse this with Java?

Comment: What do you _want_ your code to do if it can't find the locality, and so `userProperty` is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code. To create a new object in Kotlin, you don't write the word `new` like you do in Java. Also, as you have noticed, `find` returns a *nullable* type - `Property?`. You need to check for nulls when using `userProperty`. A `Property` matching the criteria you want may not necessarily be found, after all.

```
if (userProperty != null) {
    Collections.sort(packagesArray, SortPlaces(userProperty.Latitude, userProperty.Longitude))
} else {
    // no property is found! Think about what you should do in such a case
}
```

Since you are sorting the list in line, you should not make an immutable list with `toList` when you are deserialising the JSON, but rather a `MutableList`:

```
val packagesArray = gson.fromJson(inputString, Array<Property>::class.java).toMutableList()
```

Also, you seem to be using a lot of Java APIs. In Kotlin, a lot of the Java APIs that you are using have more idiomatic Kotlin counterparts. To sort the list, you don't need the `SortPlaces` class at all. Simply use [`sortBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-by.html) on the array, and call your `distance` function in the lambda.

```
data class Property(
    val pcode: Int,
    val locality: String,
    val state: String,
    val comments: String,
    val category: String,
    val longitude: Double,
    val latitude: Double,
    )


fun distance(fromLat: Double, fromLon: Double, toLat: Double, toLon: Double): Double {
    val radius = 6378137.0 // approximate Earth radius, *in meters*
    val deltaLat = toLat - fromLat
    val deltaLon = toLon - fromLon
    val angle = 2 * asin(
        sqrt(
            sin(deltaLat / 2).pow(2.0) +
                    cos(fromLat) * cos(toLat) *
                    sin(deltaLon / 2).pow(2.0)
        )
    )
    return radius * angle
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val running = true

    while (running) {
        val inputStream = File("./src/main/kotlin/suburbs.json").inputStream()
        val inputString = inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
        val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
        val packagesArray = gson.fromJson(inputString , Array<Property>::class.java).toMutableList()

        println("Please enter a suburb name: ")
        val suburbName = readLine()

        println("Please enter the postcode: ")
        val postcode = readLine()

        val userProperty = packagesArray.find {
            it.locality.lowercase() == suburbName?.lowercase() && it.pcode == postcode?.toInt()
        }

        //sort the list, give the Comparator the current location
        if (userProperty != null) {
            packagesArray.sortBy {
                distance(userProperty.latitude, userProperty.longitude, it.latitude, it.longitude)
            }
        } else {
            // did not find such a property!
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me how can I get elements within the first 10km radius ?

Comment: @KhoaBui Umm... That's not what you asked for, is it? Has your problem of sorting the list been solved? If so, please consider accepting the answer. If you have encountered more problems, you can post another question, showing where exactly you are stuck.